# Synergy: Is there a way to push Win+L to all screens, not just the server?

Tags: synergy

When I hit Win+L on either of my machines I'd ideally like to be able to lock both client and server
What happens though is no matter which screen I hit the key combination... it locks the server.

I'm guessing  the OS is trapping the key sequence before it can get passed to the app to manage, so I'm happy to use a different key sequence as long as the result will be the same

Synergy 1.4.2 64 bit Beta

Comment: Not the solution you're looking for, but a shortcut with the following target will give you a clickable link to lock whatever system it's run on:  `%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation`  I keep a copy in the Quick Launch Bar of any machines I expect to access remotely.

Comment: @lszi: [`rundll32` should not be used for that.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to do this in the options section.

You can define certain keypresses in there and how they get propogated out to the individual clients.

The [manual](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/configuration.html) tells you how to do it  Look for the `keystroke` commands.

Comment: thanks Matt. it's pretty unclear and painful to do and, as I was having a bunch of other issues with it, i gave up and switched to InputDirector... PC only (and probably less capable) but easier out of the box

Comment: The link is not available now. Is there any new manual page?

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of bugs listed in the tracker that relate to sending Win+L to a client system.  I haven't gotten it to work on my system either.

> [Feature #3154 - Lock both screens when Win+L is pressed - Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/spit/issues/details/3154/)

This is how it should work. In your config file under "section: options", you should be able to add the following:

```
keystroke(Control+Alt+l) = keystroke(super+l,*)
```

That tells synergy to send <kbd>Super</kbd> (Win) + <kbd>L</kbd> to all clients and the server whenever you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>.  I don't think there is a way to intercept <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (<kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>) on the local system.

Comment: Unfortunately, as the poster commented on the synergy bugtracker, this approach only works for machines *other* than the host.

Comment: Seem not works today,  `keystroke(Control+Alt+l) = keystroke(super+l,*)` will becomes `keystroke(Control+Alt+l) = keystroke(l,*)`  automatically when Synergy startup.   My version is  Synergy 1.14.5 on Linux

Answer (score 3):

(Should work for most Gnome 3 environments, only tested against Fedora Core 21 Gnome 3)

The following work-around will allow you to hold down Control+Alt, then press k followed by l to lock the client then server.

Modify keyboard shortcut in Gnome for locking the screen from the default super+l, to Control+Alt+l. Do this on both the server and client. You can try to keep Super+l as the lock shortcut if you like, but I encountered buggy behavior with the Super key and opted to use Control+Alt+ instead.

Add the following line to the options section of your synergy.conf file

```
 keystroke(Control+Alt+k) = keystroke(Control+Alt+l,<client>)
```

Restart synergy and test that pressing Control+Alt+k then l, locks the synergy client and then the synergy server.